# converting loop with recusrion logic

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have trouble understanding recursion. How can I turn loop with recursion logic?? Here is what I have. I have followed the recursion basics to avoid infinite calls, but that makes it not call the recursive action.

```
    function getArrayOf5(array,n) {
     var result = [];

     for(i = 0; i < array.length; i+= 5){
     var arr = array.slice(i,n)
     result.push(arr)
     n+=5;
  }
   return result;
}

 function recArrayOf5(array,i,n) {

  var result = [];

  //base case
  if(i > array.length) {return;}

  //action case
  result.push(array.slice(i,n));

  //recursive case
  recArrayOf5(array,i+5,n+5);

 return result;
}
```

here is JSBin link
https://jsbin.com/giqateketi/edit?js,console

Comment: please add some input and output.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: What is the n parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
function recArrayOf5(array, n, result){
    if(array.length <= n){
        result.push(array.slice(0, n));
        return(result); //base case
    }
    result.push(array.slice(0, n));
    return recArrayOf5(array.slice(5), n, result); //recursive call
}
function getArrayOf5(array,n) {
     var result = [];

     for(i = 0; i < array.length; i+= 5){
     var arr = array.slice(i,n)
     result.push(arr)
     n+=5;
  }
   return result;
}
f = [8, 4, 5, 67, 1, 5, 2, 7, 9, 4, 4, 3, 7, 8, 32, 5, 3, 2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(getArrayOf5(f, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(recArrayOf5(f, 3, [])));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getArrayOf5(array, n, i) {
    var result = [];
    if (i >= array.length) 
        return result;
    result.push(array.slice(i, n));
    return result.concat(getArrayOf5(array, i+5, n+5);
} //Javascript

function getArrayOf5($array, $n, $i) {
    $result = [];
    if ($i >= count($array)) {
        return $result;
    }           
    array_push($result, array_slice($array, $i, $n));

    return array_merge($result, getArrayOf52($array, $i+5, $n+5));
} //original answer in PHP
```

What your code is doing is it's calling the function recursively, but never doing anything with the return value of the function.

To have the same output between your first and second function, you need to actually do something with the result of calling your function recursively.

I've edited the response to include the Javascript code, but I'll leave the PHP in there anyways.

Comment: @hangMan - I've edited the response to include the Javascript code for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I'm using last argument for recursion as an accumulator, and collect your result to that accumulator.

```js
function getArrayOf5(array,n) {
  var result = [];

  for(i = 0; i < array.length; i+= 5){
     var arr = array.slice(i,n)
     result.push(arr)
     n+=5;
  }
   return result;
}

function recArrayOf5(array, i, n, result) {
  
  var result = result || [];

  //base case
  if(i >= array.length) {return result;}

  //action case
  result.push(array.slice(i,n));

  //recursive case
  return recArrayOf5(array,i+5,n+5, result);
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

console.log(JSON.stringify(getArrayOf5(array,5)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(recArrayOf5(array,0,5,[]))) //at first accumulator/result is empty
```

====

I think better solution of your problem with recursion will looks somehow like this

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

function getArrayOfN(array, n, res){
  var res = res || [];
 
  if(array.length === 0) return res;
  
  return getArrayOfN(array.slice(n), n, res.concat([array.slice(0,n)]));
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getArrayOfN(arr, 5)));
```

Here in every recursion call I'm adding `slice` of first N element of array to result (accumulator) in third argument:

`res.concat([array.slice(0,n)])`,

rest of main array as the first argument: `array.slice(n)`,

and same N as a second:

`getArrayOfN(array.slice(n), n, res.concat([array.slice(0,n)]));`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is

```
//action case
result.push(array.slice(i,n));

//recursive case
recArrayOf5(array,i+5,n+5);
```

In the first call, you save the slice [] to results, call the recursive call, do nothing with the result, and return the slice you took before the recursion. When doing a recursive call, you want to either return the result of the call, or have the function alter one of the values passed, so that the work of each call gets passed along from call to call.

Note as with in other answer, you can make your base case call your recursive call, all that matters is that it does terminate, and each call is trying to do a piece of the work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not change the function signature *(the parameter list)*. Note that using a consistent naming and indentation is important if you want to easily debug and make the code more understandable.

```js
function groupByN(arr, n) {
    var result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=n) {
        result.push(arr.slice(i, i+n));
    }

    return result;
}

function groupByNRec(arr, n) {
    if ( arr.length < n ) {
        if ( arr.length > 0 )  // feel free to remove these two lines  
            return [arr];      // if you don't want the remaining items
        return;
    }

    var item = arr.slice(0, n);
    var remaining = groupByNRec(arr.slice(n), n);

    return remaining ? [item].concat(remaining) : [item];
} 
    
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByN(arr, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByNRec(arr, 3)));
```

`return remaining ? [item].concat(remaining) : [item];`: this line uses the ternary operator *( `condition ? true : false` )* and test if `remaining` is undefined or not. You can also write:

```
if ( remaining )
    return [item].concat(remaining);
return [item];
```